# How to Check if Arrays in a Object Are All Empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I need to pass in a object where each of its properties are arrays.  The function will use the information held in each array, but I want to check if the whole object is empty empty (not just having no properties) by checking if each of its arrays are empty/null as well.  What I have so far:

```
function isUnPopulatedObject(obj) { // checks if any of the object's values are falsy
    if (!obj) {
        return true;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        console.log(obj[i]);
        if (obj[i].length != 0) {
            return false;
        }    
    }

    return true;  
}
```

So for example, this would result in the above being `false`:

```
obj {
    0: Array[0]
    1: Array[1]
    2: Array[0]
}
```

While this is the empty I'm checking for (so is true):

```
obj {
    0: Array[0]
    1: Array[0]
    2: Array[0]
}
```

The above code doesn't work.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So if we want to go through the object and find if every key of that object passes a check, we can use `Object.keys` and the Array#extra `every` like so:

```
var allEmpty = Object.keys(obj).every(function(key){
return obj[key].length === 0
})
```

This will set `allEmpty` to a boolean value (true/false), depending on if every time we run the given check `obj[key].length === 0` returns true or not.

This object sets `allEmpty` to true:

```
var obj = {
    0: [],
    1: [],
    2: []
}
```

while this sets it to false:

```
var obj = {
    0: [],
    1: [],
    2: [],
    3: [1]
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  It was such a solution, didn't realize objects don't have length like with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

An `object` doesn't have a length property. There are several other ways to loop through an object's values, which you should be able to [find](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20loop%20through%20object).

To check if a value is an array, you can use `Array.isArray`.

For example:

```js
function objectIsEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).every(function(key) {
      var val = obj[key];  
      
      if (Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0) {
        return true;
      }
      
      // Other rules go here:
      // ...
      
      return false;
    });
};


console.log(objectIsEmpty({ 0: [], 1: [], 2: [] }));
console.log(objectIsEmpty({ 0: [], 1: [1], 2: [] }));
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be interesting to start using the new kid in town. `Object.values()`

```
var o1 = {0: [], 1: [1], 2: []},
    o2 = {0: [], 1: [], 2: []},
chkObj = o => Object.values(o).every(a => a.length === 0);
console.log(chkObj(o1));
console.log(chkObj(o2));
```

Note: This should work only on the newest versions of Chrome, Opera and FF

Answer (score 1):

it is not working since your object doesn't have `length` property.

Try this simple one

```
function isUnPopulatedObject(obj) { 
    return Object.keys( obj ).filter( function(key){
      return obj[ key ].length > 0;  //if any array has a property then filter will return this key.
    }).length == 0; //used == here since you want to check if all are empty
}
```

or use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
function isUnPopulatedObject(obj) { 
    return Object.keys( obj ).every( function(key){
      return obj[ key ].length == 0;  
    }); 
}
```

or use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
function isUnPopulatedObject(obj) { 
    return Object.keys( obj ).some( function(key){
      return obj[ key ].length > 0;  
    }) === false; 
}
```

Comment: With a boolean result, you should use `.every()` or `.some()` so that you're not buliding a new array, and so that it can terminate early when possible. What you're using is a common workaround for jQuery deficiencies.

Comment: Use `.some()` instead of filtering. It won't create an intermediate array.

Comment: @squint `every` seems better

Comment: @4castle true, some would also do

Comment: @LaLaLottie glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

It's mentioned / done in some other answers (though not the currently accepted answer), but not emphasized:

**It's not sufficient to loop over every key and verify the length; one needs to verify the `type` of the key value, as well**, *e.g.* something like:

```
function isEmptyArray(arg) {
   return Array.isArray(arg) && arg.length === 0
}

function isObjectWhoseValuesAreAllEmptyArrays(o) {
  return Object.values(o).every( (v) => isEmptyArray(v) )        
}
```

Where you can modify `isEmptyArray` depending on the desired behaviour (e.g. throw an error if any of the keys aren't arrays *vs.* just returning false).

---

*E.g.* of cases where some of the other proposed solutions may fail:

```
var allEmpty = Object.keys(obj).every(function(key){
return obj[key].length === 0
})
```

and

```
chkObj = o => Object.values(o).every(a => a.length === 0);
```

will return `undefined` for:

- `obj = { a: [], b: '' }`, or
- `obj = { a: [], b: {} }`, or
- `obj = { a: [], b: null }`,
- *etc*

---