# Check if properties of a TypeScript object are all empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object that looks like this:

```
objectProp = {
  property1: [],
  property2: [],
}
```

I want to check if all properties(that are string arrays) if this object are null and return true.
I am for some reason stuck. How can I do this?
I am using "target": "es2015"

I tried this but does not work:

```
 if (!Object.keys(this.objectProp).every(array => array.length > 0)) {
      console.log('all are empety');
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Check if Arrays in a Object Are All Empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919560/how-to-check-if-arrays-in-a-object-are-all-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Object.keys()` you can do it as following

```js
var objectProp = {
  property1: [],
  property2: [],
}

if(Object.keys(objectProp).every(key => objectProp[key] && objectProp[key].length === 0)){
  console.log('All is empty')
}
```

Comment: it would be a nice solution but i am using "target": "es2015"

Comment: Updated as you requested

Comment: Slight logic bug, but the OP did the same `!Object.value` & `>0` with every, means if a single one is not empty, it will print `All is empty`,.. It should be `Object.values` & `<=0` with every.  Or alternatively ! and some.

Comment: I think you did not understand what i want. I want to check if ALL properties of the object are empty. Not just if only one is empty but ALL.

Comment: @Keith u are right that it does not work but the way you wrote it I do not understand. can u write it completely? thanks.

Comment: Updated again. Please have a look at

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `Object.values(this.objectProp)` instead of `Object.keys(this.objectProp)` for this to work. As [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, which is actually what you are looking for.

```js
let objectProp = {
  property1: [],
  property2: [],
}

console.log(Object.keys(objectProp))

console.log(Object.values(objectProp))
```

For Es2015, you can try this:

```js
let obj = {
  property1: [],
  property2: [],
}

// Log is print only when all arrays are empty
if (Object.keys(obj).map(e => obj[e]).every(a => a.length === 0)) {
  console.log('all are empty');
}
```

Comment: it would be a nice solution but i am using "target": "es2015"

Comment: You can use the simple polyfill then mentioned [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js)

Comment: @KathrineHanson Instead of adding that to every answer after the answer has been written, please  edit your question and add it there...

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Object.values` as follow:

```
if (!Object.values(this.objectProp).every(({length}) => Boolean(length))) {
  console.log('all are empety');
}
```

Comment: it would be a nice solution but i am using "target": "es2015"

Answer (score 0):

Most answers seem to have missed the part about your logic been slightly wrong.
They will say empty, if only single item is empty,.
This is because the logic is `!every > 0`
But switching this logic to `every <= 0` will get what you want.

eg.

The below example will return `true, true` for the broken version.
But `true, false` for the fixed one.

```js
var objectProp = {
  property1: [],
  property2: [],
};

var objectProp2 = {
  property1: [],
  property2: [],
  property3: ['not empty']
};


function allIsEmptyBroken(objectProp) {
  return (!Object.keys(objectProp).every(key => objectProp[key] && objectProp[key].length > 0));
}

function allIsEmptyFixed(objectProp) {
  return (Object.keys(objectProp).every(key => objectProp[key] && objectProp[key].length <= 0));
}


console.log('allIsEmptyBroken');
console.log(allIsEmptyBroken(objectProp));
console.log(allIsEmptyBroken(objectProp2));

console.log('allIsEmptyFixed');
console.log(allIsEmptyFixed(objectProp));
console.log(allIsEmptyFixed(objectProp2));
```